# How can I find a first occurrence of a string from a list in another string in python

Tags: python, string

I have a list of strings (about 100), and I want to find the first occurence of one of them in another string and the index in which it occurred.

I keep the index, and afterwords search again using another word list from that index on, and back to the first list until it reaches the end of the string.

My current code (that searches for the first occurrence) looks like:

```
        def findFirstOccurence(wordList, bigString, startIndex):
            substrIndex = sys.maxint
            for word in wordList:
                tempIndex = bigString.find(word, startIndex)
                if tempIndex < substrIndex and tempIndex != -1:
                    substrIndex = tempIndex
            return substrIndex
```

This codes does the job, but takes a lot of time (I run it several times for the same word lists but in 100 big strings (about ~10K-20K words each).

I am sure there's a better way (and a more pythonic way to do so).

Comment: The low-hanging fruit would be to return immediately after the first occurrence is found but I might be missing something.

Comment: What is the underlying problem that `findFirstOccurence()` solves?

Comment: Is it possible to slit the bigstring, and store the words and index into a dict, then you can look up the dict for word from the wordlist?

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the word in the list that occurs nearest the beginning of the other string?

Comment: @möter as martineau wrote I want to find the word from the list that occurs the nearest to the beginning of the string.

Comment: @Johnsyweb The underlying problem is this: I have a text comprised of two interleaved sections. I know a section (with some degree of certainty) starts with of a one of a list of distinct words. For example, lets say I have a wikipedia article written by two authors and I know each uses a unique set of words.

Answer (score 1):

This seems work well and tells you what word it found (although that could be left out):

```
words = 'a big red dog car woman mountain are the ditch'.split()
sentence = 'her smooth lips reminded me of the front of a big red car lying in the ditch'

from sys import maxint
def find(word, sentence):
    try:
        return sentence.index(word), word
    except ValueError:
        return maxint, None
print min(find(word, sentence) for word in words)
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner with list comprehension would be

```
return min([index for index in [bigString.find(word, startIndex) for word in wordList] if index != -1])
```

But I would argue if you split it into two lines its more readable

```
indexes = [bigString.find(word, startIndex) for word in wordList]
return min([index for index in indexes if index != -1])
```

Comment: You don't need an inner list for `min()`

Comment: Yes. But in this case I am filtering out -1 with list comprehension. That is why I have used an inner list for `min()`. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def findFirstOccurence(wordList, bigString, startIndex=0):
    return re.search('|'.join(wordList), bigString[startIndex:]).start()

wordList = ['hello', 'world']
bigString = '1 2 3 world'

print findFirstOccurence(wordList, bigString)
```