# Python to search a string for the first occurrence of any item in a list

Tags: python, string

I have to parse a few thousand txt documents using python, but right now I'm getting the code working for just one.

I am trying to find the first time any month (January, February, March, etc) appears in the document, and return the position of that first month.  Every document has at least one month in it, but some have many months.

This works currently, but seems very cumbersome:

```
mytext = open('2.txt','r')
mytext = mytext.read()

January = mytext.find("January")
February = mytext.find("February")
March = mytext.find("March")
April = mytext.find("April")
May = mytext.find("May")
June = mytext.find("June")
July = mytext.find("July")
August = mytext.find("August")
September = mytext.find("September")
October = mytext.find("October")
November = mytext.find("November")
December = mytext.find("December")

monthpos = [January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December]
monthpos = [x for x in monthpos if x != -1]
print min(monthpos)
 # returns the first match as a number
```

I would like to combine something like any() and find() to get the job done, but there doesn't seem like a better way to do this.  I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919171/how-can-i-find-a-first-occurrence-of-a-string-from-a-list-in-another-string-in-p) but it isn't so clear, so it didn't help that much.  While I know this is wrong and does not work for many reasons, here is what I want to do:

```
mytext = open('text.txt','r')
mytext = mytext.read()
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
print mytext.find(months) #where this would find the first time any month is matched
1945 # return the location in the string where the first month is found
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would do what you want:

```
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", 
          "May", "June", "July", "August", 
          "September", "October", "November", "December"]
indices = [s.find(month) for month in months]
first = min(index for index in indices if index > -1)
```

First, we get the first appearance of each month (or `-1` if not present), then we get the minimum of the indices, except where it's `-1`. This will throw a `ValueError` if none are found, which may or may not be what you want.

---

As Two-Bit Alchemist has commented, you could short-cut for efficiency:

```
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", 
          "May", "June", "July", "August", 
          "September", "October", "November", "December"]
first = None
for month in sorted(months, key=len):
    i = s[:first].find(month) # only search first part of string
    if i != -1:
        if i < first or first is None:
            first = i
        if i < len(month): # not enough room for any remaining months
            break
```

Comment: You can split the first list comprehension up into a normal for loop if you want to make it more efficient, for instance if it can short-circuit rather than calculating the whole list.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist that is a good point, I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: That worked really well.  Thanks so much for the quick response.  I'll run it over the larger batch of files to see how quickly it returns what I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `re` for conceptual simplicity. It's also easy to extend the code to do something more complex if you need to later.

```
import re
mytext = open('text.txt','r')
mytext = mytext.read()
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
months_match = re.search("|".join(months), mytext)
print match_obj.start()
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html